# Replacing specific characters in python list

Tags: python, string, algorithm, pandas

I have a list named `university_towns.txt` which has a list as follows:

```
     ['Alabama[edit]\n',
        'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\n',
        'Florence (University of North Alabama)\n',
        'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\n',
        'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\n',
        'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\n',
        'Troy (Troy University)[2]\n',
        'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3]      [4]\n',
        'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]\n']
```

I want to clean this text file such that all the characters in parentheses are replaced by '' . So, I want my text file to look like:

```
['Alabama',
 'Auburn',
 'Florence',
 'Jacksonville',
 'Livingston',
 'Montevallo',
 'Troy',
 'Tuscaloosa,
 'Tuskegee',
 'Alaska',
 'Fairbanks',
 'Arizonan',
 'Flagstaff',
 'Tempe',
 'Tucson']
```

I am trying to do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file = open('university_towns.txt','r')
lines = files.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(file)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace('[edit]','')
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(r' \(.*\)','')
```

With this, I am able to remove `'[edit]'` but I am not able to remove the string in `'( )'`.

Comment: Saurav Agarwal, it looks like your last edit rolled back some good edits from someone else. Please re-apply your own edits, but ensure you refresh your screen first, so that the prior edits are preserved. I have rolled back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regex should do the trick.

```
import re
output = [re.split(r'[[(]', s)[0].strip() for s in your_list]
```

Comment: This is not showing the expected output, It is showing output as : [ ] which is an empty list. @mVChr

Answer (score 1):

You may use `regex` along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
import re

new_list = [re.match('\w+', i).group(0) for i in my_list]
#       match for word ^             ^ returns first word
```

where `my_list` is the original `list` mentioned in question. Final value hold by `new_list` will be:

```
['Alabama', 
 'Auburn', 
 'Florence', 
 'Jacksonville', 
 'Livingston', 
 'Montevallo', 
 'Troy', 
 'Tuscaloosa', 
 'Tuskegee']
```

Comment: This is just giving output as : [ ]

Comment: Note this would fail for a city like `Grand Rapids` due to the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` method on a string replaces an actual substring. You need to use regex:

```
import re
#...
line[i] = re.sub(r' (.*)', '', line[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` instead of `replace`

```
import re
# your code here
lines[i] = re.sub(r' \(.*\)','', lines[i])
```

Comment: That wasn't all the code... just pointing out `replace` takes a substring but you need to use regex. What error are you getting?

Comment: @SauravAgarwal, how doctorlove already wrote, it's not all the code, it's only example of your line 'lines[i] = lines[i].replace(r' \(.*\)','')' to change